# fromiter() gives "int() argument must be a string"

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I am having a trouble with running fromiter over the array:

```
>>>import numpy as np
>>>arr = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
>>>brr = np.array([2, 4])
>>>def fnc(arr, b):
>>>    ar[br] += 2
>>>    ar[br-1] += 1
>>>    ar[br+1] += 1
>>>fnc(arr, brr[0])
>>>arr
array([0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
>>>np.fromiter((fnc(arr, brrel) for brrel in brr), brr.dtype)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

Just curious: why could this happen? Any ideas? Many thanks!

Comment: Yes. Your `fnc` returns `None` So your generator that you pass to `np.fromiter` simply keeps giving back `None` until it is exhausted.

Comment: Thank you very much, juanpa.arrivillaga. And... what if I would like to use the same array and keep the changesin it, applying fnc() many time to it and using the "brr" array to locate the spots I need to change in "arr"? Is it even possible to vectorize such a procedure? Thank you.

Comment: Um, `np.fromiter` creates a new array from an iterator. It sounds like you want to *mutate your array*. I would ask a question about how to vectorize, but it has nothing to do with `np.fromiter`

Comment: I see. I understand. I probably will use regular loops. Thank you again.

Comment: Regular loops will be slower, but that might be good enough. You can always implement a C-extension and corresponding `ufunc` if you want this to be vectorized. Cython makes this easier. But is what you are trying to do something that might already have a solution in `scipy`, for example?

Comment: In reality I have a graph represented by table approx 50 by 11, where rows are nodes and the first column is carnality of the node and last 10 columns is the list of adjacent neighbors. This is part of MiniMax, so I am trying to find a fast way to run delete operation very fast. delete() sets the cardinality of the deleted nodes to zero, uses adjacent neighbors lists to locate rows corresponding to their neighbors and decrements them by 1. I will lok if SciPy has some tools for such tasks, thank you.

Comment: So, why are you using `numpy` for this? Are you planning on using a bunch of built-in linear-algebra routines?

Comment: No I do not plan to do this. I do not have any experience with other libraries. And this is my MOOC assignment, so I guess, I can not use some blackbox library to run minimax. I have to implement it by myself. I am not very experienced with Python. I never used SciPy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake, there is no need in vectorizing it, Python can do it by itself:

```
>>>import numpy as np; a = np.zeros(10); b = np.array([1,3,5]); a; b;
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
array([1, 3, 5])
>>>def fnc(arr, b):
>>>    ar[br] += 2
>>>    ar[br-1] += 1
>>>    ar[br+1] += 1
>>>
>>> fnc(a, b)
>>> a
array([ 1.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```